# Is it possible to include the box-shadow in the div area that responds to a click event?

Tags: css, touch, mouseevent, box-shadow

I have a `div` acting as a round button. It is styled so that a significant part of its overall appearance comes from a `box-shadow`:

```html
<body style="background:black">
<div id="button" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background: yellow; border: none; border-radius: 50px; box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #c03, 0 0 2px 7px #fff"></div>
</body>
```

I have a click event listener attached to the button `div`. Unfortunately, it doesn't respond if the `div` is clicked on the `box-shadow` as the `box-shadow` is rendered outside the `div`.

This is particularly a problem on touch devices where the finger sometimes doesn't hit the center of the `div`. (Of course, it responds normally if the click is within the div's 50px area.)

Is it possible to make the event listener respond to clicks on the `box-shadow` as well as the actual `div`?

I realise I can use a separate and larger transparent div over the top of the button and attach the event listener to that, but is such a workaround necessary?

(The button `div` must be styled with `box-shadow`. I can't use the `border` property or increase `padding`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, changing the `box-shadow` to an `inset` shadow will make the area occupied by the shadow also clickable. An `inset` box-shadow is actually added **within the element** and hence even a click on the shadow is treated as a click on the `div`.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var btn = document.querySelector("#button");
  var btnOriginal = document.querySelector("#button-original");

  btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("I have been clicked");
  });
  btnOriginal.addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("I have been clicked");
  });
}
```

```css
#button {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px 2px #fff, inset 0 0 0 7px #c03;
}
#button-original {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #c03, 0 0 2px 7px #fff;
}

/* Just for demo */

#button {
  margin: 10px;
}
#button-original {
  margin: 17px;
}
div:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
body{
  background: black;
```

```html
<div id="button"></div><!-- modified version -->

<div id="button-original"></div><!-- original version -->
```

The following are some points that need to be considered while changing the shadow to an inset one:

- Since the `box-shadow` is added inside, the height and width of the `div` should be increased by a bit to make sure the final outcome is the same size as your original version. In the normal `box-shadow` version, the size of the shape would be the container's radius + spread radius.
- You may also have to adjust some margins like I have done in the sample below.
- Any blur that is added to the shadow will now be applied inwards (that is, the blur will blend with the inner part of the container and not the body). We can do nothing about this.

<sup>**Note:** In the above snippet, I have replaced the inline style attribute's contents with CSS.</sup>

---

If you want the second shadow (the white colored one) to blur towards the outside and blend with the body background, you could replace the `box-shadow` with `radial-gradient` like in the below sample. But there are two drawbacks of using `radial-gradient`, one is it has lower browser support and second is the curves are not very smooth when the element's size is very small.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var btn = document.querySelector("#button");
  var btn2 = document.querySelector("#button-2");

  btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("I have been clicked");
  });
  btn2.addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("I have been clicked");
  });
}
```

```css
#button {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 50%, transparent 57.5%, #c03 57.5%, #c03 65%, #fff 65%, transparent 72%);
}
#button-2 {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 50%, transparent 57.5%, #c03 57.5%, #c03 65%, #fff 65%, transparent 72%);
}
div:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
body {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div id="button"></div>
<div id="button-2"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. To retain the blur on the outermost shadow I added an additional thin and blurred shadow that wasn't inset.

Comment: @meatsim: Sorry, didn't realize the blurred white shadow because of the background. You can achieve that also with an inset. I have updated the snippet in the answer. You just have to change the order and the spread radius.

Comment: That looks great, thanks. I should have included a dark background in my question snippet.

Comment: The blur in your example is appearing inside the white shadow and is blending with the red shadow. I would prefer it to be on the outside and blending with the body background.

Comment: @meatsim: Ah, in that case I don't think there is any option but to add a separate outset `box-shadow` and unfortunately that part of it won't trigger a click event.

Comment: But the larger red shadow still does trigger and that's the important bit. I settled on `box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px #fff, 0 0 1px 2px #fff inset, 0 0 0 7px #c03 inset;`